# Access attributes inside hashed column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following class:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data
end
```

Profile has a single column `data` that holds a serialized hash.  I would like to define accessors into that hash such that I can execute `profile.name` instead of `profile.data['name']`.  Is that possible in Rails?

Comment: This should do it: `def method_missing(method, *args, &block) ; self[:data][method.to_s].presence || super(method, *args, &block) ; end` It's dynamic but the test `profile.respond_to? :name` will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple straightforward way:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data

  def name
    self.data['name']
  end

  def some_other_attribute
    self.data['some_other_attribute']
  end
end
```

You can see how that can quickly become cumbersome if you have lots of attributes within the data hash that you want to access.

So here's a more dynamic way to do it and it would work for any such top level attribute you want to access within `data`:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data

  def method_missing(attribute, *args, &block)
    return super unless self.data.key? attribute
    self.data.fetch(attribute)
  end

  # good practice to extend respond_to? when using method_missing
  def respond_to?(attribute, include_private = false)
    super || self.data.key?(attribute)
  end
end
```

With the latter approach you can just define `method_missing` and then call any attribute on `@profile` that is a key within `data`. So calling `@profile.name` would go through `method_missing` and grab the value from `self.data['name']`. This will work for whatever keys are present in `self.data`. Hope that helps.

Further reading:

http://www.trottercashion.com/2011/02/08/rubys-define_method-method_missing-and-instance_eval.html

http://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods/

Answer (score 1):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data # always a hash or nil

  def name
    data[:name] if data
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question.  It looks like ActiveRecord::Store is what I want:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

So my class would become:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :data, accessors: [:name], coder: JSON
end
```

I'm sure everyone else's solutions work just fine, but this is so clean.

Comment: Good stuff, didn't know about that one. I'm almost as excited as when I learned about the Dirty module! http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data # always a hash or nil

  ["name", "attr2", "attr3"].each do |method|
    define_method(method) do
      data[method.to_sym] if data
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is extremely flexible and your model is just a Ruby Class. Define the "accessor" method you want and the output you desire.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data

  def name
    data['name'] if data
  end
end
```

However, that approach is going to lead to a lot of repeated code. Ruby's metaprogramming features can help you solve that problem.

If every profile contains the same data structure you can use `define_method`

```
[:name, :age, :location, :email].each do |method|
  define_method method do
    data[method] if data
  end
end
```

If the profile contains unique information you can use `method_missing` to attempt to look into the hash.

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if data && data.has_key?(method)
    data[method]
  else
    super
  end
end
```